# Using array to add totals to a CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a script that currently runs a SQL query and writes the selected data to a CSV. This is working perfectly. However, I need to modify it so that it writes the data (which is grouped by customer service rep extension) and adds a new row beneath the records for each agent and totals their numbers.

I have formatted one of my CSVs in excel to show what I need, but I need the script to do it automatically. I have 2 columns that just have numbers to be summed but my other columns either have an indicator 'x' or they are blank. So in excel I had to formulate this to count every space that has an 'x' in it. I"m not sure how to do this all programatically through PHP or SQL in my script.

Here is the CSV as it's currently written:
[image]

Here it is after I format it how I want (I only bolded and colored the row to show the totals. I don't need to do this in the script):
[image]

So I started a modified version of the working script to try and write the CSV with the new total lines, but when I run this in powershell, it says that there is an undefined index for 'extension', on the line where I declare the variable `$extension` on `$row['extension']`. Can someone help me put these pieces together?

Here's the current script that's failing:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn2,
"SELECT
      firstn
    , lastn
    , extension
    , Recieved
    , RecievedKnown
    , Outbound
    , outboundKnown
    , Missed
    , MissedKnown
    , CallingNumber
    , CalledNumber
    , starttime
    , endtime
      , duration
    , HOLDTIMESECS
    , TERMINATIONREASONCODE

FROM (
      SELECT
              u.firstn
            , u.lastn
            , c.extension
            , CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND ANSWERED = 1 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS Recieved
            , CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND answered = 1 AND CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS RecievedKnown
            , CASE WHEN ANSWERED = 1 AND LEGTYPE1 = 1 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END  AS Outbound
            , CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 1 AND FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO = k.phone_number THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS outboundKnown
            , CASE WHEN Answered = 0 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS Missed
            , CASE WHEN ANSWERED = 0 AND CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS MissedKnown
            , a.CALLINGPARTYNO AS CallingNumber
            , a.FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO AS CalledNumber
            , b.starttime AS starttime
            , b.endtime AS endtime
            , b.duration
            , a.holdtimesecs
            , a.terminationreasoncode
      FROM ambition.session a
      INNER JOIN ambition.callsummary b ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
      INNER JOIN ambition.mxuser c ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
      INNER JOIN jackson_id.users u ON c.extension = u.extension
      LEFT JOIN ambition.known_numbers k ON a.callingpartyno = k.phone_number
      WHERE date(b.ts) >= curdate()
      AND LEGTYPE1 <> 12 -- This keeps the report from having blank spaces due to the 12 legtype.
      AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)

      ) x
    ORDER BY lastn") or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));


    $fp = fopen('newDailyTest.csv', 'w');
    $userDetails = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
        /*  take the extension as the key to store its respective counts */
        $extension = $row['extension']; //this is where the undefined index error is
        /*  while loop calculations  */
        if(!isset($userDetails[$extension])){

            $userDetails[$extension]['missedCallCounts'] = 1; /* First time count */
        }else{
            $userDetails[$extension]['missedCallCounts'] += 1; /* Sum up the count */
        }
    }

    foreach($userDetails as $userDetail){
/* In the following line dump the respective userdetails to csv which will show summary */
fputcsv($fp, array_values($userDetails));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the constant `MYSQLI_NUM` for `fetch_array`'s argument, but you want `MYSQLI_ASSOC` so that an associative array is returned rather than an integer indexed array.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ //replace in this line
```

Comment: I did this, and that bypassed the error but now it's giving an array to string conversion notice? My CSV is just columns full of the word 'array'

Comment: I think you meant `array_values($userDetail)` instead of $userDetails.  This will still however just output the counts that you are wanting in the csv. It looks like somewhere in this script you need to write each $row array to the csv as well.